# Ordenação de array baseado na ordem de outro array

Tags: javascript, array

Seguinte, tenho dois vetores cada um com uma sequência numérica. Vamos chamá-los de `Array1` e `Array2`. Os valores estão abaixo...

`Array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
Array2 = [7, 6, 3, 9, 4, 5, 1, 10, 8, 2];`

A minha dúvida é como eu faria para ordenar os valores do Array1, fazendo com que a ordem dos valores seja igual ao do Array2. Por exemplo, no lugar do Array1 cujo valor é "1", ele colocaria o valor que está na mesma posição (index), só que no Array2. No caso ele trocaria pelo "7". Enfim, alguém teria um palpite?

Comment: Os teus arrays de exemplo são iguais. Neste caso ficariam os dois iguais.

Comment: É exatamente isso o que eu pretendo fazer, @Miguel . Eu ordeno o array1 a partir da posição dos mesmos valores no array2

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que ambos os arrays possuem os mesmos valores (embora ordenados de forma distinta), e que a reordenação do array 1 o deixaria "equivalente" ao array dois, você poderia fazer isto:

```
array1 = array2;
```

Mas dessa forma os dois arrays serão clones, ou seja, a mesma coleção de números, i.e.: as alterações que forem feitas em um afetarão igualmente o outro. Se quiser realmente uma cópia, faça:

```
array1 = array2.slice(0);
```

Invejosos dirão que ambas as formas são trapaça.

Comment: Bah, eu não sabia desse slice... Vou usar direto ele agora.

Comment: @GabrielPolidoro existem outras formas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop Isso pode ser interessante pois assim poderá reconhecê-las se as vir no código de outras pessoas.

Comment: Não será uma cópia verdadeira, pois ainda há ponteiros: https://jsfiddle.net/f1baf543/

Answer (score 1):

Se quiseres somente duas arrays iguais podes fazer:

```
arrayA = arrayB;
```

ou até mesmo

```
arrayA = arrayB.slice();
```

porém isso não impede que elementos da array sejam referênciados de uma array para a outra, uma vez que eles não foram copiados, mas sim "apontados".

**Exemplo:**

```js
var array1 = [{id:1, desc: 'foo'}, {id:2, desc: 'bar'}];
var array2 = array1.slice();

array1[0].desc = 'olé!';
console.log(array2[0]); // vai dar "olé" apesar de estar na array da cópia
```

Se tiveres uma array de elementos Primitivos o melhor é passar para string e de volta para array. Assim crias cópias em profundidade

**Exemplo:**

```js
var array1 = [{id:1, desc: 'foo'}, {id:2, desc: 'bar'}];
var array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1));

array1[0].desc = 'olé!';
console.log(array2[0]); // vai dar "foo"
```