# Como ordenar um vetor (A) de acordo com outro vertor (B) (contendo números repetidos) em javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**problemática:** Eu tenho uma tabela com perguntas, Para cada tipo de Intervençao eu carrego determinadas perguntas. Preciso mostrar essas perguntas em uma tela de conclusão, para esse tipo de Intervenção específico. O que define a sequencia das perguntas é o tipo de intervenção.

**Exemplo:**
BANCO:

- perguntas: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

**Perguntas por intervenção:**

- Intervencao1:  2, 3, 5, 9, 10.
- Intervencao2: 1, 9, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4.
- Intervencao3: 5, 6, 9, 4, 2, 1.

O Problema, é que as perguntas são mostradas também, de acordo com a resposta. 
Posso ter numa Intervenção, que comece com a pergunta 1, se o usuário responder SIM, carrega as perguntas 2, 3, 5. Se ele responder NÃO, carrega as perguntas 9, 8, 5, 2.

E posso ter perguntas repetidas, para a mesma intervenção. Como no exemplo do Código.
Mas, para essa mesma pergunta, o usuário, pode ter respostas diferentes. E na conclusão, deve aparecer de modo correto a pergunta relacionada a resposta. Na ordem.

---

tenho o seguinte código:

```js
let intervencao = [{id:1},{id:5},{id:6},{id:7},{id:8},{id:9},{id:10},{id:11},{id:12},{id:12},{id:12},{id:12},{id:12},{id:12},{id:12},{id:13},{id:14},{id:15},{id:16},{id:17},{id:18},{id:19},{id:20},{id:21},{id:22},{id:23},{id:24},{id:25},{id:26}];
    
    function sortIntervencao(dados) {
     let sort = [];
       
     intervencao.forEach(p => {
      sort[dados.findIndex(x => x === p.id)] = p;
     });
      return sort;
    }
        
    let dados = [1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,12,15,16,12,17,18,12,19,20,12,21,22,12,23,24,12,25,26];
    
    let sortDados = sortIntervencao(dados);
    console.log(sortDados);
```

Preciso que o Objeto intervencao, seja ordenado de acordo com o objeto dados.

perceba, que dados, tem varios "12" repetidos no decorrer do vetor.

Preciso que o Intervencao fique da mesma forma.

Porém, quando rodo o código, o primeiro "12" fica certo, os outros somem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro Problema, é que esse intervenção, nem sempre terá todos os campos.

Por exemplo:

```js
let intervencao = [{id:1},{id:6},{id:7},{id:8},{id:9},{id:10},{id:11},{id:12},{id:12},{id:12},{id:12},{id:12},{id:12},{id:13},{id:14},{id:15},{id:16},{id:17},{id:21},{id:22},{id:23},{id:24},{id:25},{id:26}];
    
    function sortIntervencao(dados) {
     let sort = [];
       
     intervencao.forEach(p => {
      sort[dados.findIndex(x => x === p.id)] = p;
     });
      return sort;
    }
        
    let dados = [1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,12,15,16,12,17,18,12,19,20,12,21,22,12,23,24,12,25,26];
    
    let sortDados = sortIntervencao(dados);
    console.log(sortDados);
```

por isso não pode ser uma cópia exata. conforme [essa resposta aqui!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198612/ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-array-baseado-na-ordem-de-outro-array)

Veja rodando aqui: [código](https://jsfiddle.net/rebecanonato/dmx92wg5/32/)

Comment: O código no jsFiddle não está funcionando. Troque esta linha ` altert(sortDados.foreach(x => x.id));` por `sortDados.forEach(x => console.log(x));`.

Comment: O problema é que `dados.findIndex(x => x === p.id)` vai sempre achar o mesmo índice para sort quando o p.id for igual. Assim, por exemplo, para o objeto `{id:12}` na posição `intervencao[9]`, o `dados.findIndex` vai retornar 8, e vai colocar esse objeto em `sort[8]`; mas para `{id:12}` em `intervencao[10]`, `dados.findIndex` vai retornar 8 novamente, e vai então sobrepor o objeto em sort[8]. Você pode ver bem isso colocando essa linha `console.log(p, dados.findIndex(x => x === p.id));` no `intervencaoforEach()`.

Comment: Sim, dá para perceber isso exatamente no segundo código, quando o campo não tem. Ele coloca o espaço em branco. Mas, como resolver isso? Posso colocar uma condição?

Comment: Qual condição? Quais os outros atributos dos objetos? O que define que intervencao[9] deve ficar em sort[8], e intervencao[10] em sort[11]? Você teria que colocar na pergunta qual o problema real que você está tentando resolver.

Comment: atualizei a pergunta, com o problema como um todo.

Comment: infelizmente ainda não entendi a relação do código com a pergunta. `intervencao`, no código seria um roteiro para um tipo de intervenção? `dados` seria uma intervenção real, com as perguntas feitas de acordo com as respostas do usuário? Mas nesse caso, porque haveria perguntas repetidas na intervenção (12 - você já tentou ligar e desligar? 12 - você já tentou ligar e desligar?)? E porque ordenar intervenção ao invés de para cada item de dado buscar a intervenção correspondente? De qualquer modo, veja minha resposta.

Comment: vou implementar ela aqui, e fazer uns testes. Mas, acho que a sua solução resolveu o problema. Vou testar aqui. E marco como resposta. Obrigada. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é manter um array com o último índice encontrado para um id, e usando a função `indexOf()` fazer a busca a partir desse último índice ao invés de sempre a partir do começo do array:

```
function sortIntervencao(dados) {
    let sort = [];
  let idxs = [];

    intervencao.forEach(p => {
    let id = p.id;
    let start = idxs[id] ? idxs[id] + 1 : 0;
    let idx = dados.indexOf(id, start);
    console.log(p, idx);
        sort[idx] = p;
    idxs[id] = idx;
    });
        return sort;
}
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/zbjn89r7/2/).

Obs.: essa é uma solução para o problema abstrato apresentado. Dependendo do problema real, pode haver uma solução mais adequada.